# Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

> Generating PDf using tibonilab/pdf-lumen-bundle in Lumen 
>   Its always shows the error like below image
>   [image: Displaying Error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: \_\_autoload() is deprecated, use spl\_autoload\_register() instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045274/error-autoload-is-deprecated-use-spl-autoload-register-instead)

Comment: I tried this way its not works yet !!